# My Aquia Dev Desktop is insanely slow. What could be the problem?

Tags: database, acquia-dev-desktop

I'm running Drupal 7 with the latest version of Aquia Dev Desktop and the site is REALLY slow on local host. I mean something like one minute to load a node  to edit it, and three minutes to load the modules page.

I tried the Boost module, and I have all the performance settings maxed out.   What could the problem be (a port, the PHP version, too many installs)? I have about seven sites in there.

The site on the live server (in the USA) is faster and I'm connecting from Thailand; that is twice as fast as localhost.

Comment: There are literally dozens of things that could be responsible for a site being slow, please provide some more details about what's causing the problem and flag for reopening. If you think it's not your own configuration but rather an inherent problem with the software you're using, please report this to them as a bug. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same thing when I tried using the Acquia Dev Desktop.

I now use [c9.io](https://c9.io/) (clould 9) and do all my development in the cloud `:)`

Here is a nice [overview video of the IDE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UX0mqLVlauk).

Comment: I looked at your profile, form lower mainland? I'm from Vancouver, send me a message from my site? I'll try your suggestion. Cheers!